# VMware shows windows ( ubantu ) loading but do not open

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I'm using VMware workstation to run a ubantu based software software . First it was running fine , but suddenly when I open .vmx file and power on the virtual machine , it start to starting fine . But after some point it become black screen
Generally after this , main virtual window should show up so that we can start working . But it do not .
What can I do. I uninstall VMware and reinstall it many time but do not help.

My Host OS is Windows 10 
VMware workstation version 10
before gone into black, this is the [last screen][2]

and suddenly I noticed there is a warning also shown which I do not understand a bit :
"The configuration default for GNOME Power Manager have not been installed correctly.Please contact your computer administrator."

thanks in advance . I'm not sure I can make up properly understand my problem. sorry .

EDIT: text boot log [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBSeX.jpg)

Comment: You should post the VMware log that is typically located in the same directory as your virtual machine vmx, vmdks, etc.  make sure you cut any personal info out first. Also what OS is the host running on, what version of VMware, what Ubuntu release and other specifics. If you can identify the last thing on the screen before the vm fails that may help

Comment: I edit the post and give as much as info I can

Comment: When Ubuntu is booting, click in the virtual machine window and hit escape. This will change the display from the graphical boot screen to the text boot log. The last entry before it hangs may or may not be the power mgmt warning, but it will almost certainly be the reason it isn't continuining. At that screen, depending on where in the boot process it hangs, you can also get a terminal window by hitting alt-F2. Hit alt-F1 to return to the boot screen. If you can get to the terminal take a look at the system logs; journalctl , dmesg , or /var/log/messages.

Comment: display changes to "text boot log" alright,  but hitting alt-F2 have no effect. can not get terminal window.

Comment: Can you post that text?

Comment: I give an screen shot in EDIT

Comment: Alright - that shows a grub screen for CentOS... I don't think I can help you, sorry.